# PL\SQL - OWA_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL open in new tab

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PL\SQL, is it possible to open a URL in a new tab/window, instead of the existing one?

I know there is the `OWA_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL` function, but this makes the current page redirect to the specified URL. I would like to open the URL in a new tab or window.

For example:

```
OWA_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL('https://google.com')
```

will redirect the current browser tab to `google.com`, when I would like to keep the current tab open and open a new tab/window to `google.com`

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. PL/SQL is a programming language, it doesn't have tabs or pages. You must be programming with PL/SQL in some sort of client. The big ones, sqlplus, sqlcl, or SQL Developer aren't web-based. What are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. `OWA_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL` is like a redirect in `.htaccess` file. There you cannot specify "open in new tab" either. You would need to deploy some JavaScript in your page.

A solution similar to this might work:

```
HTP.PRINT ('<html><head>');
HTP.PRINT ('<script type="text/javascript">');
HTP.PRINT ('window.onload = function () {');
HTP.PRINT ('  var url = "https://google.com";');    
HTP.PRINT ('  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');');
HTP.PRINT ('  win.focus();');
HTP.PRINT ('}');
HTP.PRINT ('</script>');
HTP.PRINT ('</head><body></body></html>');
```

Comment: JavaScript was the solution I eventually came to. I looked around for probably a few hours with no luck in finding a function for what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect using **OWA_UTIL.REDIRECT_URL** and assign variable :status to **X-ORDS-STATUS-CODE** in OUT headers

like this:

[redirect with X-ORDS-STATUS-CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALxcc.png)

```
DECLARE
    l_url varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
    l_url := 'https://google.com/';
    owa_util.redirect_url(
        curl            => l_url,
        bclose_header   => TRUE
     );
    :status := 303;
END;
```